# Execute multiple functions / run a script without having to open the web apps script interface

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, button, google-drive-api

I need to a way to execute a script / multiple functions without having to open the Google Web Apps menu all the time.

The point of the script / functions I'm using is to input/update the names of sub-subfolders in a google drive folder as cells in google sheets.

I've borrowed a script from stackoverflow regarding said topic and it works fine, but I'm having trouble executing said script or series of functions utilizing a button.

Script as mentioned:

```
var folderId = 'folderId';

function listFolders(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

function listAll(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resources");
    sheet.clear('A1');
    sheet.appendRow(["Name"]);

    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [ 
      childFolder.getName()
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(data);

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName()
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }

    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};

function appendToColumn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resources");
  var data = "End";
  //Get the column where you want to append the data
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().flat();
  var row = range.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(row);
  sheet.getRange(row+1,2).setValue(data);
}
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392651/google-sheets-script-one-button-with-two-consecutive-functions-function-1-run) that you can make a function execute multiple functions, and assign that function to a button, i.e.

```
function button1(){
  listFolders();
  listAll();
  etc...
// then assign button1 to a button
```

However, the functions I'm using are a bit different hence I can't just write a string of functions.

Comment: The easiest way to create buttons is in html.  Try creating a side bar and then add buttons and then attach the buttons to javascript and then attach the javascript to google.script.run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you really need a button ? Using a custom menu is a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, and no it doesn't have to be a button; as long as it's a simple way to execute multiple functions / the script I've provided.  If its not too much trouble, I'd like to know how to create a custom menu to execute the specific script / functions I've provided. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

gs:

```
function executeFunctionByName(func) {
  this[func]();
}

function getProjectFunctionNames() {
  const vfilesA=getGlobal('sbfiles').split(',');
  const scriptId="1JO1n6EpiKlORws9J-icjffuKdGX6l-4vgYmRJtUTdg88efz7hwatg_09";
  const url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content?fields=files(functionSet%2Cname)";
  const options = {"method":"get","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let html=res.getContentText();
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Project Functions");
  let data=JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  let funcList=[];
  let files=data.files;
  files.forEach(function(Obj){
    if(vfilesA.indexOf(Obj.name)!=-1) {
      if(Obj.functionSet.values) {
        Obj.functionSet.values.forEach(function(fObj){
          funcList.push(fObj.name);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(funcList.join(', ')), "Project Functions");
  return funcList;
}
```

html:

```
<br /><input type="button" value="run1()" onClick="execFunc1();" /><select id="func1"></select>

<script>

$(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
      let idA=["func1","func2","func3","func4"];
      idA.forEach(function(id){
        updateSelect(vA,id);
      });
    })
    .getProjectFunctionNames();
}
function updateSelect(vA,id){
    var id=id || 'sel1';
    var select = document.getElementById(id);
    select.options.length = 0; 
    vA.unshift("");
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
      select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
    }
  }
 function execFunc1() {
    var funcname=$('#func1').val();
    google.script.run.executeFunctionByName(funcname);
  }
</script>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However I have to ask if there are parts of the script that I need to replace?

Comment: I could not see what your example had to to with your question so I just provided you with way I answered the question several years ago.  How you wish to use it is up to you.

Comment: I just need to execute the functions I've provided using a button or some other comprehensive way without having to open google web apps script all the time. I've updated my question to give a little more detail concerning the situation; currently I'm having trouble navigating through your example and how to adapt it to my script.

Comment: I feel like this answer provides me with the greatest flexibility.  I use it in the tool that I write all of the examples with and if greatly facilitates the testing of my code.